# What will happen to the REST api if the http methods and the implemented CRUD operations are different?

Tags: rest, http

Quoting [REST](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/) documentation,

> REST guidelines suggest using a specific HTTP method on a particular type of call made to the server (though technically it is possible to violate this guideline, yet it is highly discouraged).

I want to know what will happen if I violate this guideline? Because ultimately it's up to me what functionality I put in the API. I even tried this out. I used `http` method `get` and implemented delete functionality in it. To my surprise, it worked just fine. I was hoping to get some warning or error but got nothing.

So, does it mean that `REST` is just a standard to follow, and not following it, won't break my API? Is my API not restful anymore? What is it?

Please forgive the naivety of my query. I am quite new in this area.

Answer (score 0):

For background: the authoritative definition of REST is [Fielding's dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).  REST isn't a standard, it's an [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5).

HTTP is a standardized application protocol.  HTTP is one of the pillars of the world wide web, which is *the* reference application influenced by the REST architectural style.

So what we have is a standard that describes what HTTP messages mean (for instance, that the request method token is the primary source of [request semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.1), subject to some further clarification by other meta data provided with the request).  Because we have this standard, we can build a lot of general purpose components (like web browsers, or caches) that can do intelligent things because they understand the broad semantics of the request.

> I used http method get and implemented delete functionality in it. To my surprise, it worked just fine.

Yup, it does.  Until it doesn't.

Here's Fielding [writing about that topic in 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html):

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the sake of this definition).

Note: the "fault of the implementation" bit.

The broad problem is this: the semantics of GET are [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), it therefore follows that a general purpose component can GET a resource any time it might be convenient to do so -- for example, when crawling the web like Google, or pre-fetching a web page into a browser to reduce latency in case the user wants to click the link.

General purpose components are allowed to assume your resources understand messages the same way everything else on the web does, that allows us to have smarter general purpose components, which is the point of the uniform interface constraint.

If we get your resource, and you delete something because that's what you do when you handle a get request, and damage is a consequence of that delete... that's your fault.